# Which conditions does the geoJSON file read from the server in?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I've added an alert to the function myReadFunction in order to detect function calls.

As according to my observations, the function readMyFunction is called sometimes while I have been navigating on the map, not every time. The function readMyFunction has not been called when a feature is being viewable or not during map navigation. Could you please explain in which conditions the geoJSON file is read from the server?

```
 mVectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: 'http://localhost:56786/jlist.geojson',
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'read': myReadFunction,
                'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            })
        }),
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
    });
```

Thanks a lot for your helps and clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) : Rreads new features when the viewport invalidates some bounds.

Try adjusting the [resFactor](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html#OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX.resFactor) {Float}

> Optional factor used to
>   determine when previously requested features are invalid.  If set, the
>   resFactor will be compared to the resolution of the previous request
>   to the current map resolution.  If resFactor > (old / new) and
>   1/resFactor < (old / new).  If you set a resFactor of 1, data will be
>   requested every time the resolution changes.  If you set a resFactor
>   of 3, data will be requested if the old resolution is 3 times the new,
>   or if the new is 3 times the old.  If the old bounds do not contain
>   the new bounds new data will always be requested (with or without
>   considering resFactor).

You can also play around with the ratio to see if this helps. Default is 2.